# Enabling local data store on Parse by calling enableLocalDatastore before initialization disables user caching

Tags: ios, parse-platform, ios8, local-datastore

When using Parse in my app, if I enable Local Datastore - [Parse enableLocalDatastore]; - the logged in user does not get cached [PFUser currentuser] returns null when I relaunch my app;

I am using Parse SDK v1.6.1

Anyone experienced this? and if yes have you got any solution?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem since the v1.6.1, have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @RJiryes it turns out the problem is only on the device, it works just fine on a simulator. So the problem is LocalDataStore is not working on the device.